# I am trying to use strings inside an array and then splitting that string into its characters

Tags: c++

Consider:

```
std::string words[Maxword] = { "Hello", "World", "Shift", "Green" , "Seven" };
srand(time(NULL));
int iSecret = rand() % 4 + 1;
std::cout << words[iSecret];
```

I have this code which has an array with words in it. Then it picks a random number and that correlates to a word. How then would I split that word into the letters?

Similar to world, it would be later compared to a letter that the user would guess.

Comment: `words[iSecret]` should be a `std::string`, in which case you can get the characters as a `char*` with `words[iSecret].c_str()`

Comment: What do you mean by *"Similar to world"*? Do you mean *"Similar to [Wordle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wordle)"*?

Answer (score 0):

Note sure what you are asking but you can do this to access a character in a string

```
 std::string s = "Word";
 std::cout << s[1]; // == 'o'
```

you can loop

```
 for(int i = 0; i << s.length(); i++){
      std::cout << s[i];
 }
```

Comment: But the program will pick a word from that array so how do I split the string that it has picked into its charecters

Comment: @Kameron replace 's' above by 'words[x]'

Comment: for (int i = 0; i << words[iSecret].length(); i++) {
        std::cout << words[i];   
    }   When i do this nothing comes up on console so i can see if its actually split it into characters

Comment: @Kameron see edit, I had typo. Please dont treat what I entered as a maigc spell, read it and understand it

Comment: Get a load of the upvoted answer -- I guess we just don't measure up... Very strange.

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of options. Both can be handled in the same manner. With your array of `std::string`, to split the selected word into characters (in a manner where you can provide a second random index and retrieve that character), you could do:

```cpp
  std::cout << words[iSecret] << "\n\n";

  for (size_t i = 0; i < words[iSecret].length(); i++) {
    std::cout << "words[iSecret][" << i << "]:  '" <<
                (char)words[iSecret][i] << "'\n";
  }
```

Above, since `words[iSecret]` is type `std::string`, you can use the `[ ]` index operator to select any character at a valid index within `words[iSecret]`. For all ways of accessing individual characters, you can see [std::basic_string](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string).

If you did not need individual character access by index and simply wanted to loop over each character, you could use a *range-based* `for` loop, e.g.

```cpp
  for (const auto& c : words[iSecret])
    std::cout << (char)c << '\n';
```

**Example Use/Output**

Where running the program with the index operator `[ ]` for access as shown above, it would produce:

```
$ ./bin/splitwords-char
Green

words[iSecret][0]:  'G'
words[iSecret][1]:  'r'
words[iSecret][2]:  'e'
words[iSecret][3]:  'e'
words[iSecret][4]:  'n'
```

or

```
$ ./bin/splitwords-char
Seven

words[iSecret][0]:  'S'
words[iSecret][1]:  'e'
words[iSecret][2]:  'v'
words[iSecret][3]:  'e'
words[iSecret][4]:  'n'
```

**std::vector As Alternative to array-of-std::string**

If you have control over the type for `words`, then making it `std::vector<std::string> words {...}` avoids the inflexible limitation of the array-of-`std::string`. How you access each character would be exactly the same. Whether an element of `std::vector<>` or an element of the array, the type of the object you are dealing with is still `std::string`.

In addition to the index operator `[ ]`, you can also use the member function `.at()` (e.g. `words[iSecret].at(i)` with the benefit that `.at(i)` also provides bounds checking on the index provided. See [std::basic_string::at](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/at)

**Precedence Problem**

You have an error in your use of `rand()`. `%` (modulo) has a higher precedence than `+`, so you never access `"Hello"` (you only access elements `1` to `4`). See [C++ Operator Precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence). To correct the problem either enclose `(4 + 1)` in parenthesis, or simply use `rand() % Maxword`. That way the values will range from `0` to `4` allowing access to all indexes in `words[]`.